# Changing a component's attribute un subscribe method

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular-http, angular-httpclient

I am currently developing an Angular 4 app. I am using a restful web service to get data from the database.

I created a front end service called `UsersListService` which has a method which returns an observable to which I have subscribed in my component. I want to change the component's attribute users to the data returned by the web service but unfortunately the component's attribute is always set to its default value.

So once the page is loaded, I got the data returned by the web service but once I make search or pagination users is set to it's default value ["1","2","3"].

This is the service method:

```
getUserList(){
    //this method is returning the items 
            return this.http.get(this.usersUrl)
            .map(res => {
                this.users=res['items'];
               return this.users;
            });
            
        }
```

This is my component:

```
import {User} from '../../auth/shared/user';
import {CreateUserComponent} from '../create-user/create-user.component';
import {UpdateUsersCredentialsComponent} from '../update-users-credentials/update-users-credentials.component';
import { Component, OnInit, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
import { MdDialog } from '@angular/material';
import{UsersListService} from '../shared/users-list.service'
@Component({
  selector: 'vr-users-list',
  templateUrl: './users-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./users-list.component.scss']
})
export class UsersListComponent implements OnInit,AfterViewInit {
  private users:any[]=["1","2","3"];
  constructor(public dialog: MdDialog,private userListService: UsersListService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    
      this.userListService.getUserList().subscribe (
    data =>{
    console.log("those are data "+data.length);    
    this.users=data;
   

});
 
      
  }
  ngAfterViewInit(){
    this.userListService.getUserList().subscribe (
      data =>{
      console.log("those are data "+data.length);    
      this.users=data;
     
  
  });
   
  }
  openUsersDetails() {
    this.dialog.open( UpdateUsersCredentialsComponent);
  }
  openCreateUser() {
    this.dialog.open( CreateUserComponent);
  }

}
```

this is my html

```
<div class="container">

        <div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="space-between center">
            <vr-breadcrumbs [currentPage]="'users'" ></vr-breadcrumbs>
            <div fxLayout="column" fxLayoutAlign="end">
              <h5>  <div class="value" [vrCountUp]="{suffix: '  users' }"   [startVal]="0" [endVal]="240">88</div>
              </h5>
              </div>
           
              <button type="button" md-fab color="primary" (click)="openCreateUser()">  <i class="fa fa-user-plus"></i></button>
         
          </div>
        
<table datatable class="row-border hover">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>First name</th>
      <th>Email</th>
      <th>Position</th>
 
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
      <tr *ngFor="let data of users"  (click)="openUsersDetails()" >
          <td>{{data.login}}</td>
          <td>"test"</td>
          <td>"test"</td>
          <td>"test"</td>
      </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: set [currentPage]="  users " without single quotes

Comment: it's not that the problem

Comment: <vr-breadcrumbs [currentPage]="'users'" ></vr-breadcrumbs>

Comment: it's a menu so it should be like that.It's not reposible for data display

Answer (score 0):

thank's to this article i solved my problem: https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/02/22/angular-2-change-detection-explained.html

i deteched the ui chnages so this is my component's code

```
import {CreateUserComponent} from '../create-user/create-user.component';
import {UpdateUsersCredentialsComponent} from '../update-users-credentials/update-users-credentials.component';
import { Component, OnInit, OnChanges, ChangeDetectionStrategy, ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';
import { MdDialog, MdDialogRef, MdDialogConfig } from '@angular/material';
import{UsersListService} from '../shared/users-list.service'
import { User } from 'app/pages/Users/shared/user';
@Component({
  selector: 'vr-users-list',
  templateUrl: './users-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./users-list.component.scss'],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class UsersListComponent implements OnInit,OnChanges {
  private users:any[]=["1","2","3"];
  private selectedUser:User;
  constructor(public dialog: MdDialog,private userListService: UsersListService,private cd: ChangeDetectorRef) { 
  }

    public get $selectedUser(): User {
        return this.selectedUser;
    }

    public set $selectedUser(value: User) {
        this.selectedUser = value;
    }
  ngOnChanges(){
this.cd.detach();
  }
  ngOnInit() {

      this.userListService.getUserList().subscribe (
    data =>{
    console.log("those are data "+data.length);    
    this.users=data;
    this.cd.markForCheck(); // marks path


});


  }

  openUsersDetails() {


    let config = new MdDialogConfig();
    let dialogRef:MdDialogRef<UpdateUsersCredentialsComponent> = this.dialog.open(UpdateUsersCredentialsComponent, config);
    dialogRef.componentInstance.email =this.selectedUser.$email;
  }
  openCreateUser() {
    this.dialog.open( CreateUserComponent);
  }

}
```